# SQL query with conditions for audit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a SQL query for several columns with conditions. the table looks like this:

```
ID          Company           User
1           Bov               LPF
2           Ak                LPF
3           Bov               LPF
4           Bov               ABC
5           Ak                ABC
6           ZP                ABC
7           REP               ABC
8           REP               CDE
9           KEK               CDE
10          Ak                CDE
11          PER               CDE
12          Bov               BKE
```

The result must be as followed:

- Give me three rows per user (only the users with at least three rows will be in the result).
- Company Bov, REP and Ak must return at least two times in the result
- It is for an audit so everything must be ordered randomly (order by newid() for example)
- Total rows is 9.

Expected result for example:

```
ID          Company          User
 1           Bov               LPF
 2           Ak                LPF
 3           Bov               LPF
 4           Bov               ABC
 5           Ak                ABC  
 7           REP               ABC
 8           REP               CDE
 10          Ak                CDE
 11          PER               CDE
```

How should i write the query?

Update:

I was thinking about a query like this, but this doesn't give me the right results:

```
 select *
  from
  (
  select *,row_number() over(partition by user,company order by user, company) as row, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by newid()) as total
  from
  (
  select *
  from
  (
  select *, 0  as Bov, sum(iif(Company= 'Ak',1,0)) over (order by newid()) as Ak
  FROM table a 
  where Company = 'Ak'
  ) as eu
  where eu.Ak <= 2
  UNION ALL
  select *
  from
  (
    select *, sum(iif(company = 'Bov',1,0)) over (order by newid() )  as Bov, 0 as Ak
  FROM table a
  where Company = 'Bov'
  ) as nn
  where nn.Bov <= 2
  UNION ALL
    select *, 0 as Bov, 0 as Ak
  FROM table a
  where Company not in ('Bov','Ak')
  ) as z
  ) as z1
  where z1.row <= 3
  and z1.total <= 9
```

Filter `<= 2` is for the company that must return at least two times in the result
Filter `row <= 3` is for the three rows per user.
Filter `total <= 9` is for the total rows that must be 9.

With this query i am not for sure that i have at least two rows for the companies Bov, Ak and REP.

Comment: This looks a LOT like homework. You need to at least make an attempt.

Comment: Start with `select`. When you have a _specific_ question then post it with all of the applicable details. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your next question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select *
 from table
 group by id
 having count(User) <= 3
 order by id
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that isn't what i want, because in my result i need for every user three rows (the users with less than three rows can be skipped, for the users with more than three rows it have to random select three rows). Next to that i also need two rows for the company Bov, REP and Ak in the result (two rows with company Bov, two rows with REP and two rows with Ak).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID INT, Company VARCHAR(10), [User] VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1  , 'Bov', 'LPF'),
(2  , 'Ak ', 'LPF'),
(3  , 'Bov', 'LPF'),
(4  , 'Bov', 'ABC'),
(5  , 'Ak ', 'ABC'),
(6  , 'ZP ', 'ABC'),
(7  , 'REP', 'ABC'),
(8  , 'REP', 'CDE'),
(9  , 'KEK', 'CDE'),
(10 , 'Ak ', 'CDE'),
(11 , 'PER', 'CDE'),
(12 , 'Bov', 'BKE')


SELECT ID, Company, [User] FROM 
    ( SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Company IN ('Bov','REP','Ak') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ) RN
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [User]) CmpCnt
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN Company IN ('Bov','REP','Ak') THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [User]) PriCmpCnt
    FROM @MyTable
    ) T
WHERE 
    T.CmpCnt > 2
and T.PriCmpCnt > 1
and T.RN < 4
order by ID
```

Result:

```
ID          Company    User
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Bov        LPF
2           Ak         LPF
3           Bov        LPF
4           Bov        ABC
5           Ak         ABC
7           REP        ABC
8           REP        CDE
10          Ak         CDE
11          PER        CDE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach it; see comments for explanation / let me know if you need anymore info to understand anything...

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b88/6)

```
;with cte as 
    (
        select Id
        , Company
        , [User]
        , Row_Number() over (partition by [User] order by randomOrder) PerUserRowNum 
        , case 
            when Company in ('BOV','REP', 'AK') then 
                case 
                    when Row_Number() over (partition by Company order by randomOrder) <= 2 then 1
                    else 0
                end
            else 0 
        end  MustInclude
        from (select *, newid() randomOrder from SourceData) x
    )
    select top 9                --total rows is 9
    Id, Company, [User]
    from cte
    where PerUserRowNum <= 3    --show 3 rows per user
    and [User] in ( --only the users with at least three rows will be in the result
        select [User]
        from cte 
        where PerUserRowNum = 3
    )
    order by MustInclude desc, newid() --ensure all the stuff we must include is returned, then make up the rest of the results with whatever
```

Comment: Hi JohnLBevan, thanks for your answer but it doesn't give me the right answer. When i use the temporary table like we use in the other comments i don't get the three rows per user i want. I also get BKE in the results (its only once in the source table).

Comment: Apologies; missed the brackets on the `User` field.  Since User is a keyword it needs to be `[User]` to ensure it returns the column value instead of the current schema.  To avoid such issues I try to avoid using keywords as column names.  Now corrected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b88/2

Comment: Thanks, the three rows per user is perfect now. But i don't always get the two rows for each company (Bov, REP and Ak).

Comment: Ah sorry @Ray; since `newid()` was being generated each time it didn't play well with the `row_number()` function; I've amended to return the IDs first, then use those to determine the sequencing.  Hopefully that now plays well.

Comment: i still don't get the two rows for each company with your new query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b88/8

Comment: Ah sorry; looks like the logic to restrict us to 3 users removes some of the records which have those companies as "must include"... think the best fix is to do the company logic in the initial query, then restrict the users in a later query, prioritising those flagged as "must include"... will play in a bit, but don't have a chance right now...